# Advertisements are missing a plural check

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

See below, "1 open jobs". For an ad, looks especially unprofessional.

[image]

Comment: [Be careful when reporting a bug like this.](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Comment: Jeff Atwood isn't at SO anymore, right? So hopefully I'll be safe?

Comment: @DLeh He didn't say anything about SO, so you're not really safe.

Comment: Given it's an ad, perhaps SO will care on behalf of their clients even if they don't care themselves.

Comment: but these ads are build by so in some way, right? they've got the relevant tags and stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No worries, you're safe :)

This has been fixed and should be deployed in the next half hour or so. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: [tag:status-completed], ya?

Comment: whoops, yeah. it's done :)